# Azure Devops Pipeline, DOTNET_BUNDLE_EXTRACT_BASE_DIR is not set, and a read-write cache directory couldn't be created

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to run **efbundle.exe** in my azure pipeline, but it is giving me this error.

```
Failure processing application bundle.
Failed to determine location for extracting embedded files.
DOTNET_BUNDLE_EXTRACT_BASE_DIR is not set, and a read-write cache directory couldn't be created.
##[error]Bash exited with code '159'.
```

This is my yml file (the relevant part)

```yaml
- stage: 'Deploy'  
  jobs:
    - deployment:
      strategy:
       runOnce:
         deploy:           
           steps:
             - bash: |
                chmod +x $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/drop/efbundle.exe
                $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/drop/efbundle.exe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be related to the user's permission. The app is trying to extract the bundle, but the user doesn't have write permission on the extraction directory.

The solution is to set the extraction directory like so:

```yaml
- stage: 'Deploy'  
  jobs:
    - deployment:
      strategy:
       runOnce:
         deploy:           
           steps:
             - bash: |
                export DOTNET_BUNDLE_EXTRACT_BASE_DIR="$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/.net"
                chmod +x $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/drop/efbundle.exe
                $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/drop/efbundle.exe
```